# Limit "each" list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have this:

```
<% @shops.each do |shop| %>
  <li><%= shop.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

The code will yield the total result of 50 entries (in my case).

How can I limit this view to 20? Yeah, just limit it, I don't want any pagination or what.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that stuff coming from a database? Then just limit it there using ActiveRecord.

Comment: It's actually a thinking sphinx search result. I have set it as 50 per page, because I wanna show 50 google maps markers, but in the list, I wanna show just 20.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change the code in your controller where `@shops` is being set, or change the above code to `@shops.take(20).each`.

Comment: I use `@shops.take(20).each` instead, because I need 50 results elsewhere in the same page. Thanks!

Comment: Say you have a user.post association and you want to have an index page that only shows one post from each user. How would you limit there? Something like <% posts.user_id.limit(1).each do |user| %>? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 20):

I would highly suggest using your database to limit the results. This is much more efficient in that your database is doing the work(it is designed to do this) AND you aren't retrieving all your results then filtering them. Imagine if you had 1 million results that you asked your database for... not very desirable.

You'd want to do:

```
Shop.limit(20)
```

Which has the database doing the work rather than Ruby.

A quick benchmark test (Comments table only contains 487 results!):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :033 > Benchmark.ms do
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :034 >     Comment.all.take(20)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :035?>   end
 => 649.461030960083 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :036 > Benchmark.ms do
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :037 >     Comment.limit(20)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :038?>   end
 => 0.1506805419921875
```

~4,300 times worse!

Or even if your argument is that you have a small amount of results returned, here is another benchmark:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :041 > Benchmark.ms do
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :042 >     Comment.limit(50).take(20)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :043?>   end
 => 410.9840393066406 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :044 > Benchmark.ms do
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :045 >     Comment.limit(20)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :046?>   end
 => 0.05412101745605469
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your research. I was actually using Sphinx to search, but am now thinking of just using `all.paginate` upon your recommendation.

Comment: You absolutely want to limit your results for 1) User Experience 2) Performance.

Comment: In this case there is only 50 comments returned. So perfomance will be not so critical

Comment: Yes, but this really isn't going out of the way to gain performance( whether small or otherwise)

Answer (score 10):

Just `limit` it on your ActiveRecord level (or SQL)

```
@shops = Shop.limit(20)        # Rails 3+
@shops = Shop.all :limit => 10 # Rails 2+
```

Or use Ruby

```
<% @shops[0,20].each do |shop| %>
  <li><%= shop.name %></li>
<% end %>
```