# Break out of conditional block in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to break out of the if condition if the index is greater than 5 after appending the icon in my row. Right now it keeps on adding the icon.

```
<div class="row sub-navigation">
  <% @projects.each_with_index do |project, index| %>       
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">                                  
    <% if index > 5 %>
      <%= link_to "", path, remote: true, id: "project_div", 
                class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" %>
    <% else %>      
      <%= link_to project.name, project_url(project.project_id), class: ('active' if current_page?(project_path(project.project_id)) ) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use `break`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`break`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm)

```
<% @projects.each_with_index do |project, index| %>
   <% break if index < 5 %>
<% end %>
```

--

Or you could also use `.take` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624548/limit-each-list-in-rails):

```
<% @projects.take(5).each do |project| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

This will allow you limit the value of the loop to 5 objects only, preventing the need for further logic

---

`break` is a common programming function, designed to get out of a loop

What `Dax` and I were suggesting was to add it along-side your `if` statement:

```
<% if index < 5 %>
    <% break %>
<% else %>
     ... do something
<% end %>
```

If you just want to add an icon for the first 5 links, you'll want to do this:

```
<% your_class = index > 5 ? nil : "icon_class" %>
<%= link_to "path", path_helper, class: your_class %>
```

--

**Update**

In response to your pastie, here's what you need to do:

```
<div class="row sub-navigation">
  <% @projects.each_with_index do |project, index| %>       
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">               
    <% your_class = index > 5? "icon_class" : nil %>
    <% link_to "", path, remote: true, id: "project_div", class: your_class %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, let me update for you. Break it is own function - not a replacement for if :)

Comment: I cannot use take as i need to append an icon once it reaches 5. I need the index to know if 5 iteration is complete.

Comment: why was the first one not working and second one inside <% break %> working.

Comment: Because break is its own function - using `<% break if index < 5 %>` only determines if Index is above 5 - if it is, it breaks the loop. The second way put break inside the conditional statement, allowing the statement to run before the break had to be called

Comment: I want to add icon to my last column.... not to every item... i have a row with 6 items... once it reaches the 6... i need to add a icon for drop-down.

Comment: Okay you probably won't need `break` per se - how are you calling the icons? Is it with an img or class?

Comment: <%= link_to "", path, remote: true, id: "project_div", 
                class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" %>

Comment: via above way, i am adding an icon to row when the condition reaches 6 and breaks out of loop.

Comment: So you only want that class if the loop is above 6?

Comment: So why can't you use the update I gave above with ternary if?

Comment: I saw that code, but i am not sure on how to implement it. http://pastie.org/private/gpnlrycnb03ynjrkuc9xa

Comment: What does "your class" correspond to. <% your class = index > 5 %> I am confused here... coz i need to list the project too if its less than 5 like this <%= link_to project.name, project_url(project.project_id), class: ('active' if current_page?(project_path(project.project_id)) ) %>

Answer (score 1):

You can try `<% break if index > 5 %>`